# Selenium NoClassDefFoundError for SSLContext

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to the selenium testing. While working with a website I am getting one error: **"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts**

Can you please help me with this?

**Here is my sample code**

```
public class TutorialsPointDownload {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/acceptance_testing.htm");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/aside/div[2]/div/ul[1]"));
        List<WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(we.size());
     }
}
```

**Console output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContexts
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:252)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
    at TutorialsPointDownload.main(TutorialsPointDownload.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

**Dependency Added:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs due to the fact that SSLContext has been relocated to another package in httpClient >= 4.4.Therefore we need to upgrade the httpCore dependency to 4.4 or any new version.

Answer (score -2):

Try to create a desired capability and set

```
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```